# Select the first td with class using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the first td with class free (td class="free" ..).
How to select the first td on page load. How to achieve this jquery or javascript?? Please help...

Since it was not clear to many people I will explain it briefly. I have an option for the customer to select the available time for their delivery and basically I wanted to select the first time for them so I wanted to save one click for them but they can change it if they want to. The available time's class is free that's what I asked the above question.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/first

Comment: Addition to ^^^^^^ `$('td.free').first()`

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/a87re62p/

Comment: **[Google search : select first td with class jquery](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=select+first+td+with+class+jquery&spell=1)**

Comment: There are so many possibilties, why not just use google (or bing or whatever) at first ?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple

```
$('td.free').first();
```

Example:

```js
console.log($('td.free').first().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="free">3</td>
    <td class="free">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$('td.free:first')
```